# Multiple images not showing in viewpage

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following controller method to retrieve files in a folder.

```
    public JsonResult filesinfolder(ProductEdit model)
    {
        string productid = "01";

        string salesFTPPath = "C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/rootProject/project_name/project_name/Content/Essential_Folder/marketing_materials_EN/01";
        DirectoryInfo salesFTPDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(salesFTPPath);
        IEnumerable<string> files = salesFTPDirectory.GetFiles()
          .Where(f => f.Extension == ".xls" || f.Extension == ".xml" || f.Extension == ".jps" || f.Extension == ".jpg" || f.Extension == ".jpeg" || f.Extension == ".png" || f.Extension == ".PNG")
          .OrderBy(f => f.Name)
          .Select(f => f.Name);

        // build urls
        model.ImageUrls = new List<string>();

        foreach (string name in files)
        {
            model.ImageUrls.Add(Url.Content("~/Content/Essential_Folder/marketing_materials_EN/" + productid) + "/" + name);
        }

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

then In view page I'm showing those files using following tags and scripts

`<li id="idd"></li>`

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("filesinfolder", "Home")', // don't hardcode
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                var img = $('<img>').attr('src', item);
                $("#idd").append(img);
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        }
    });
});
```

But using this I can do preview only if this specific folder has one file, when it comes multiple files in folder those files are not previewing in Viewpage

Comment: first check does 'data' returns all the files name and $.each loop iterate same time?

Comment: You are returning images from controller through `model.ImageUrls` but in js you are have put the `$.each` on data which is actual model. Should it not be `data.ImageUrls`?

Comment: Yes. Try with returning model.ImageUrls

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers in jsonresult return `model.ImageUrls` should change ?

Comment: Yes, you can also check returned data in js for confirmation

Comment: In this folder [I have following images](http://i.imgur.com/a0MWbJ9.jpg) then when I'm viewing those images in view page those images [appearing like this](http://i.imgur.com/jfrNsJm.jpg) ,

Comment: Can you post how items are added into `model.ImageUrls.Add(Url.Content("~/Content/Essential_Folder/marketing_materials_EN/" + productid) + "/" + name);`. Based on your  images added in comments it seems that at client, image source is not recognized properly.

Comment: cant understand what you said ?

Comment: My question was what is the result of line `Url.Content("~/Content/Essential_Folder/marketing_materials‌​_EN/" + productid)`?

Comment: @user1672994 its [like this](http://i.imgur.com/6z52g8r.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Change your implementation to iterate over data.ImageUrls as Controller action return model object which wraps the imageUrls.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("filesinfolder", "Home")', // don't hardcode
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
            $.each(data.ImageUrls, function (index, item) {
                var img = $('<img>').attr('src', item);
                $("#idd").append(img);
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        }
    });
});
```